Frontend not communicating with API in dockercontainers
I'm making a simple website application for my studies. The problem is my teacher never explained anything, didn't give us any notes just expects a fully made working application. So I have been working on it for a couple of weeks now with AI help ofcouse since I'm a beginner with no experience and my teachers don't explain anything. So I made a database firstly in mssql, but since then I learned that it had trouble connecting though docker because I was using "Trusted Connection" so i transfered to PostgreSQL, later I've made API in .NET 8.0 and made frontend in react. The project is working locally on my machine, but when I put it in containers it won't add anything into the database and won't fetch data to display, so I think the problem must be in communicating from front to back, but i have trouble localising the issue and have no idea how to fix it. I will display a code for one part of the project since i guess the problem will be the same for all other parts as well.
So for my API this would be the model for my clients:
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace CarWarehouseAPI.Models
{
    public class Client
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public List<Purchase> Purchases { get; set; } = new List<Purchase>();
    }
}


This would be the controller for clients:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CarWarehouseAPI.Data;
using CarWarehouseAPI.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CarWarehouseAPI.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class ClientController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly CarWarehouseContext _context;

        public ClientController(CarWarehouseContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }

        [HttpGet("getAll")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetAllClients()
        {
            return Ok(await _context.Clients.ToListAsync());
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> GetClientById(int id)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.FindAsync(id);

            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(client);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult<Client>> AddClient([FromBody] Client client)
        {
            _context.Clients.Add(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtAction(nameof(GetClientById), new { id = client.Id }, client);
        }

        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateClient(int id, [FromBody] Client client)
        {
            if (id != client.Id)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            _context.Entry(client).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!ClientExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpGet("byName/{clientName}")]
        public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Client>>> GetClientsByName(string clientName)
        {
            var clients = await _context.Clients
                .Where(c => c.Name.Contains(clientName))
                .ToListAsync();
            return Ok(clients);
        }

        [HttpPatch("{clientId}/connectWithPurchase/{purchaseId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ConnectClientWithPurchase(int clientId, int purchaseId)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.FindAsync(clientId);
            var purchase = await _context.Purchases.FindAsync(purchaseId);

            if (client == null || purchase == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            client.Purchases.Add(purchase);
            _context.Clients.Update(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpPatch("disconnectWithPurchase/{purchaseId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DisconnectClientFromPurchase(int purchaseId)
        {
            var clients = await _context.Clients
                .Where(c => c.Purchases.Any(p => p.Id == purchaseId))
                .ToListAsync();

            foreach (var client in clients)
            {
                client.Purchases.Remove(client.Purchases.First(p => p.Id == purchaseId));
                _context.Clients.Update(client);
            }

            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpPatch("disconnectWithAll/{clientId}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DisconnectClientFromAllPurchases(int clientId)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.Include(c => c.Purchases).FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.Id == clientId);

            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            client.Purchases.Clear();
            _context.Clients.Update(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DeleteClient(int id)
        {
            var client = await _context.Clients.FindAsync(id);

            if (client == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            _context.Clients.Remove(client);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return NoContent();
        }

        private bool ClientExists(int id)
        {
            return _context.Clients.Any(e => e.Id == id);
        }
    }
}


This would be the main part for API Program.cs (I'm sorry for the comments in polish they are mainly for me)
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using CarWarehouseAPI.Data;
using CarWarehouseAPI.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Dodaj DbContext do kontenera usług
builder.Services.AddDbContext<CarWarehouseContext>(options =>
    options.UseNpgsql(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"))); // Zmieniono na PostgreSQL

// Dodaj usługi kontrolerów
builder.Services.AddControllers();

// Dodaj usługę CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins",
        policy =>
        {
            policy.AllowAnyOrigin()
                  .AllowAnyHeader()
                  .AllowAnyMethod();
        });
});

var app = builder.Build();



// Użyj polityki CORS
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


And this is the dockerfile for API
# Use the official .NET SDK image to build the app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:8.0 AS build
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the project file and restore dependencies
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy the rest of the application files and build the application
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Use the runtime image for running the application
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:8.0 AS runtime
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/out .

# Expose the port the app runs on
EXPOSE 80

# Set the entry point for the container
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "CarWarehouseAPI.dll"]


Later in the frontend for my clients I use two components for now, one for adding one for display
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../App.css';  // Import globalnych stylów

function AddClient() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('');
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [phone, setPhone] = useState('');

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const client = { name, email, phone };

    axios.post('http://carwarehouse-api:8080/client', client)
      .then(() => {
        alert('Client added successfully!');
        setName('');
        setEmail('');
        setPhone('');
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error adding the client!', error);
      });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Add Client</h2>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Name:
          <input type="text" value={name} onChange={(e) => setName(e.target.value)} required />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Email:
          <input type="text" value={email} onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)} required />
        </label>
        <br />
        <label>
          Phone:
          <input type="text" value={phone} onChange={(e) => setPhone(e.target.value)} required />
        </label>
        <br />
        <button type="submit">Add Client</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddClient;


import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import '../App.css';  // Import globalnych stylów

function ClientList() {
  const [clients, setClients] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('http://carwarehouse-api:8080/client/getAll')
      .then(response => {
        setClients(response.data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error('There was an error fetching the clients!', error);
      });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Client List</h2>
      <ul>
        {clients.map(client => (
          <li key={client.id}>
            ID:{client.id} - {client.name} - {client.email} - {client.phone}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ClientList;


And Dockerfile for front
# Użyj oficjalnego obrazu Node jako bazowego
FROM node:18 AS build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
RUN npm run build

# Użyj prostego serwera do serwowania plików statycznych
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build /app/build /app/build
RUN npm install -g serve
CMD ["serve", "-s", "build", "-l", "80"]


And lastly this is my docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:15-alpine
    container_name: carwarehouse-postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres       # Zmień na swoje użytkownika
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: admin   # Zmień na swoje hasło
      POSTGRES_DB: CarWarehouse         # Nazwa bazy danych
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
      - carwarehouse-net

  api:
    build: ./CarwarehouseAPI
    container_name: carwarehouse-api
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Production
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=Host=postgres;Database=Carwarehouse;Username=yourUsername;Password=yourPassword;
    ports:
      - "5000:8080"
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    networks:
      - carwarehouse-net

  frontend:
    build: ./carwarehouse-frontend
    container_name: carwarehouse-frontend
    ports:
      - "3000:80"
    depends_on:
      - api
    networks:
      - carwarehouse-net

volumes:
  postgres-data:

networks:
  carwarehouse-net:
    driver: bridge


If someone would be willing to help I will appreciate it since I don't have anyone else to ask. I have no idea why the project was working locally (using different URL in front for it to work) and why it won't work in containers. I will apreciate any help you will be willing to give to me. Also I can provide other parts of my code if needed
I have already tried switching the URL names and as I said before I switched the database from mssql to postgresql. I have also tried to curl from inside the frontend container but I have received no response. I'm not sure if I should look for the root problem inside my API, my frontend or the dockerfiles since as I said I'm really new to this and this is pretty much my first time coding anything more than a simple c# for loop to display some numbers.
The errors I receive are
"ERR_NETWORK"
"AxiosError"

Your frontend code runs in the end user's browser, even if its code is served from a container.  Since it's not running in a container itself it can't see the Docker-network host names.  The linked question describes the problem in more detail, and a couple of paths to resolve this.

Yes thank you! I was working with container names and by mistake i run the containers after switching to localhost and now its working
